# Centrally search everything from Omnibox or extension in Chromium-based browsers (Chrome, Opera, etc.)

Tags: web-browser, search

I'd like to be able to type a string on Omnibox (or activate an extension hotkey) then to see a list of:

- search engine suggestion autocomplete
- history tabs containing title/URL matching the typed string
- active tabs containing title/URL or text matching the typed string
- recently closed tabs containing title/URL matching the typed string
- bookmarks containing title/URL matching the typed string
- previously typed strings containing the currently typed string

Is there an extension for Google Chrome or another browser [based on Chromium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_%28web_browser%29#Other_browsers_based_on_Chromium) that does *all* of these functions?